FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: User does not have permission to access 'image/image.jpg'. (storage/unauthorized)
FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: User does not have permission to access 'image/image.jpg'. (storage/unauthorized)  in react
FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: User does not have permission to access 'image/image.jpg'. (storage/unauthorized)

This might happen if you don't set your Firebase storage rules properly. Read more about it here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security
Note that Firestore rules and Firebase storage rules are 2 different things.
